# Index Error When Running Basic Web Scrape in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-scraping

I'm using Python 2.7. When I try to run this code, I get a problem when the function hits print findPatTitle[i], and python returns "Index Error: list index out of range". I'm taking this code from the 13th python tutorial on youtube, and I'm pretty sure the code is identical, so I don't understand why I would get a range problem. Any ideas?

```
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

webpage = urlopen('http://feeds.huffingtonpost.com/huffingtonpost/LatestNews').read()

patFinderTitle = re.compile('<title>(.*)<title>')

patFinderLink = re.compile('<link rel.*href="(.*)" />')

findPatTitle = re.findall(patFinderTitle,webpage)
findPatLink = re.findall(patFinderLink,webpage)

listIterator = []
listIterator[:] = range(2,16)

for i in listIterator:
    print findPatTitle[i]
    print findPatLink[i]
    print "\n"
```

Comment: Why are you using regex to parse the html when you have BeautifulSoup? o.O You shouldn't parse html with regex... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 0):

If you regex managed to find out the title and link tags you would be getting a list of matched strings when using the findall. In that case, you can just iterate through them and print it.

Like:

```
for title in findPatTitle:
    print title

for link in findPatLink:
    print link
```

The Index Error you are getting is because you are trying to access the list of elements from 2 to 16 and there are not 16 elements in either Titles or links.

Note, `listIterator[:] = range(2,16)` is not a good way to write code for this purpose. You could just use

```
for i in range(2, 16)
    # use i
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had a problem in my code, findPatTitle should have been <title>(.*)</title>. Sorry about that.